# how to use lucene.net to query a solr index

Tags: solr, lucene.net, lucene, dih

I have and index created using solr DIH. I want to query that index data using the Lucene.net library.

the path of solr index is D:\Tests\solr\example\example-DIH\solr\db\data\index

the code I use to create lucene index directory object is as follows:

```
Analyzer anz = new StandardAnalyzer();
Directory dir = 
 FSDirectory.GetDirectory(@"D:\Tests\solr\example\example DIH\solr\db\data\index", false);
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
```

while executing the last line of code I get the following exception:

> Could not find file
>   'D:\Tests\solr\example\example-DIH\solr\db\data\index\segments'.

Given that the files within my solr index folder are

- _0.fdt
- _0.fdx
- _0.fnm
- _0.frq
- _0.nrm
- _0.prx
- _0.tii
- _0.tis
- segments.gen
- segments_2

So what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Lucene.NET is only up to Lucene version 2.9.2.2 or so while solr is running on Lucene 2.9.3. This means that Lucene.NET can't index a SOLR index so easily.

Now, what you can do is use something like [SolrSharp](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/) to access Solr directly, sidestepping this version issue.

Comment: The problem with me is that I already use SolrNet library to query my index and I wanted to add my own assembly that references SolrNet to Sql Server assemblies and create an external function on sql that calls the code within my own assembly. Unfortunately both SolrNet and SolrSahrp References System.Web assembly which is not supported by Sql Server. So I needed to use lucene on solr index to work around this.

Comment: @SubPortal: unfortunately you can't have either SolrNet or SolrSharp without System.Web because all communication with Solr happens via HTTP.

Comment: @SubPortal: why do you want to run SolrNet on SQL Server?

Comment: @SubPortal: I recommend creating a question for running System.Web on SQL Server and another with the real reason for wanting to run SolrNet on SQL Server.

Comment: I need to run Solr from sql server because I have my data split over Sql Server and Solr and I have a Sql Server procedure with a very complex logic that works on both parts of my data.

Comment: @SubPortal: create another question with all details, I think I can help.